# Chrome, static PKP sets, and TLS inspect without warning

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, https

I'm using chrome in an environment that is employing transparent TLS inspect. There is a private CA that issues the certificates and is available in the trusted authorities store. When I visit mail.google.com I don't receive a warning. I would expect to receive a warning since the certificate issuer does not match the static pinset (https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json).

Why can I connect to google.com without a warning (e.g. pinset failure)? This is concerning to me as there is multitude of CA, any of which can potentially issue a certificate for, say, google.com.

Does certificate transparency remedy this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can I connect to google.com without a warning (e.g. pinset failure)?

Because browsers ignore pinning if the CA is one explicitly added as trusted, i.e. not one from the default CA store but still trusted. This is done to work together with **trusted** SSL interception, as done not only in corporate environments but which is also employed by various local antivirus products.

> Does certificate transparency remedy this issue?

No. See also [How effective is Expect-CT against content inspection in an enterprise context?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/218588/how-effective-is-expect-ct-against-content-inspection-in-an-enterprise-context)

Comment: Firefox has a setting to restore the behavior:

security.cert_pinning.enforcement_level=2

But doesn't seem to be an option under chrome